# raphael - SVG should be hidden when overflowing background SVG

Tags: svg, raphael

http://codepen.io/keyboardninja/pen/WQwoRg

```
var content = paper.text (70, 54, "3").attr({
  "font-size": "120px",
  "font-weight": "600",
  'fill': 'red',
});
```

I want the content of the triangle not to be visible outside of the triangle. The black background is the only place where the content should be visible on, not outside of that. is there a way to make something like to hide content that overflows the shape of the black triangle background ?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done in Raphael alone. You could probably do it if the solution was changed to Snap or CSS.

Comment: I already found a solution that works fine. I used clip paths and added them via a class to the sole object that needed the hidden overflow.